# "unknown flag: --platform" when use "docker buildx build" in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using RedHat-7 system. And I want to Jenkins Pipeline to implement Devops.
But when I use `docker buildx build` feature, Jenkins says "unknown flag: --platform".

I run my Jenkins with docker image:

```
docker run -d \
    --name jenkins \
    --restart=unless-stopped \
    -u 0 \
    --network jenkins \
    -p 8082:8080 \
    -p 50000:50000 \
    -v /home/ngtl/jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    -v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker \
    -e TZ=Asia/Shanghai \
    -e JAVA_OPTS=-Duser.timezone=Asia/Shanghai \
    jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11
```

and this is my pipeline:

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  tools {
      maven 'mvn'
  }

  environment {
    DOCKER_CREDENTIALS = credentials('clouds3n-ldap')
  }

  stages {
    stage('Unit Test') {
      steps {
        withMaven(maven: 'mvn') {
          sh 'mvn clean test -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=false'
        }
      }
    }

    stage('Maven Build') {
      steps {
        withMaven(maven: 'mvn') {
          sh 'mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip -DskipTests'
        }
      }
    }

    stage('Sonar Scan') {
      steps {
        withSonarQubeEnv('sonarqube') {
          withMaven(maven: 'mvn') {
            script {
              def allJob = env.JOB_NAME.tokenize('/') as String[]
              def projectName = allJob[0]
              sh "mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.branch.name=${env.GIT_BRANCH} -Dsonar.projectKey=${projectName} -Dsonar.projectName=${projectName} -Dmaven.test.skip -DskipTests"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    stage('Sonar Gate') {
      steps {
        timeout(time: 30, unit: 'MINUTES') {
          waitForQualityGate abortPipeline: true
        }
      }
    }

    stage('Docker Build') {
      steps {
        script {
          def allJob = env.JOB_NAME.tokenize('/') as String[]
          def projectName = allJob[0]
          final noSuffixProjectName = projectName.substring(0, projectName.lastIndexOf('-'))
          sh "echo ${DOCKER_CREDENTIALS_PSW} | docker login -u ${DOCKER_CREDENTIALS_USR} 192.168.2.157:8881 --password-stdin"
          sh "docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -t 192.168.2.157:8881/uni/${noSuffixProjectName}:dev-${BUILD_NUMBER} -f ${env.JENKINS_HOME}/k8s-config/docker/BackendDockerfile . --push"
        }
      }
    }

    stage('Maven Deploy') {
      steps {
        withMaven(maven: 'mvn') {
          sh 'mvn deploy -Dmaven.test.skip -DskipTests'
        }
      }
    }

    stage('K8s Apply') {
      steps {
        echo 'not support now, comming soon'
      }
    }
  }

    post {

      always {
        sh 'docker logout 192.168.2.157:8881'
      }

      cleanup {
        cleanWs()
      }

      success {
        echo 'Finished!'
      }
    }
}
```

When reach "Docker Build" stage, Jenkins will throw error :

```
Warning: A secret was passed to "sh" using Groovy String interpolation, which is insecure.
         Affected argument(s) used the following variable(s): [DOCKER_CREDENTIALS_PSW]
         See https://jenkins.io/redirect/groovy-string-interpolation for details.
+ echo ****
+ docker login -u **** 192.168.2.157:8881 --password-stdin
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /root/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -t 192.168.2.157:8881/uni/cqu:dev-11 -f /var/jenkins_home/k8s-config/docker/BackendDockerfile . --push
unknown flag: --platform
See 'docker --help'.
```

Why Jenkins pipleline can not use "--platform" options? How to fix this problem ?

Comment: is a container problem? jenkins container can not call buildx command from the host machine

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Jenkins agent (slave) has recent version of docker.
[BuildKit has been integrated to docker build since Docker 18.06](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/) .

In my case version 18.09.6 did not work. 20.10 is good though.

Comment: I can reproduce the error with docker 20.10.11 so that alone isn't sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

If someone happens to encounter this problem, the solution for me was to install docker desktop from the [official site](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/mac-install/).

I have MacBook Pro with Intel chip, and I installed `docker` and `docker-buildx` using Homebrew.
When I ran the command `docker buildx build --platform=linux/amd64` command I got the same error `unknown flag: --platform`.

As I mentioned, installing docker desktop solved this issue.

Comment: It didn't resolve the issue for me. I'm using MacBook with an M1 Apple chip. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I guess the difference between you and me is the chip.